# My CSS File is not applying when I link it into the HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS file `style.css` stored in a CSS folder and tried using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` to link it into the HTML file. I got a 404 not found error from this and am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Below is the code (there is not much at the moment):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}

<div class="MainBody">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <div class="w3-container w3-padding-32 w3-hide-small center-align">
        <h1>About Us</h1>
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[This shows the full path of style.css within the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qknn.png)

Please let me know what is being done incorrectly.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` the path to  style.css must be specified. Need to know which folder your html file is in first. Or use an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you answered your own question:

> I have a CSS file `style.css` *stored in a CSS folder*

Your `href` attribute should look something like: `href="/css/style.css"`

Comment: Yes, I believed so before, but when I tried it I came up with the same error.

Comment: The 404 error happens when the browser cannot find the file specified, so keep trying to get the correct path in your `href` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The href should should have the path where the file is located along the file name not only the file name.
Example :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
```

we use "./" to search in the current folder.
we use "../" If you want to come back from the current folder.

Answer (score 1):

I see this is a structure of a `Flask` app. In `Flask`, the CSS files and other assets should by default be stored in the `static` directory which should be directly inside your home directory.

Your file structure should look like this:

```
TSAWeb_App
|__ templates
    |__ index.html
|__ static
    |__ CSS
        |__ style.css
```

Then you to access it inside the web app, first import `url_for` method

```py
from flask import Flask, url_for
```

Then you can refer to CSS file as:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='CSS/style.css') }}">
```

Then when the app is run, the `href` tag will have the correct value set

---

**UPDATE:** If you're using `Django`, see this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)

> #### Configuring static files
>
> 1. Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your
>    INSTALLED_APPS.
> 2. In your settings file, define STATIC_URL, for example:
>
> ```py
> STATIC_URL = '/static/'
> ```
>
> 3. In your templates, use the static template tag
>    to build the URL for the given relative path using the configured
>    STATICFILES_STORAGE.
>
> ```py
> {% load static %}
> <img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
> ```
>
> 4. Store your static files in a folder called static in your app.
>    For example `my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In the href, would you not leave the first / off? I thought that would go to a root folder. Try and eliminate that first slash and see what happens. As was said, the 404 is because it's looking in the wrong place.